# Pearson coefficient per rows on large matrices

Tags: r

I'm currently working with a large matrix (4 cols and around 8000 rows). 
I want to perform a correlation analysis using Pearson's correlation coefficient between the different rows composing this matrix.

## I would like to proceed the following way:

Find Pearson's correlation coefficient between row 1 and row 2. Then between rows 1 and 3... and so on with the rest of the rows.

- Then find Pearson's correlation coefficient between row 2 and row 3. Then between rows 2 and 4... and so on with the rest of the rows. Note I won't find the coefficient with row 1 again...
- For those coefficients being higher or lower than 0.7 or -0.7 respectively, I would like to list on a separate file the row names corresponding to those coefficients, plus the coefficient. E.g.:
  row 230 - row 5812 - 0.76

I wrote the following code for this aim. Unfortunately, it takes a too long running time (I estimated almost a week :( ).

```
for (i in 1:7999) {
print("Analyzing row:")
print(i)    
for (j in (i+1):8000) {
    value<- cor(alpha1k[i,],alpha1k[j,],use = "everything",method = "pearson")
    if(value>0.7 | value<(-0.7)){
        aristi <- c(row.names(alpha1k)[i],row.names(alpha1k)[j],value)
        arist1p<-rbind(arist1p,aristi)

    }
}
```

Then my question is if there's any way I could do this faster. I read about making these calculations in parallel but I have no clue on how to make this work. I hope I made myself clear enough, thank you on advance!

Comment: You can avoid one nesting level in your loops if you make use of `cor` accepting matrix input.

Comment: Also, don't grow objects in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roland pointed out, you can use the matrix version of `cor` to simplify your task. Just transpose your matrix to get a "row" comparison.

```
mydf <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4), b = rep(5,2,10), c = c(1:10))
cor_mat <- cor(t(mydf)) # correlation of your transposed matrix
idx <- which((abs(cor_mat) > 0.7), arr.ind = T) # get relevant indexes in a matrix form
cbind(idx, cor_mat[idx]) # combine coordinates and the correlation
```

Note that parameters `use = everything` and `method = "pearson"` are used by default for correlation. There is no need to specify them.